# animate offset().left

Tags: jquery

I've been all over the place looking for this.  There are some answers out there but none of them work.

All I want to do is slowly move a div to the left when a user does a mouseover on a button.

This works to make the div move:

```
$("#myDiv").offset({left:-1000});
```

but all my attempts to animate the move cause the move itself to fail.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/loktar/Zswg6/ works for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use .animate() function like this

```
$("#myDiv").animate({ left: '-1000' });
```

**Update:**
Since your division is floated to the left, you can animate the property using `marginLeft` instead.

```
$("#myDiv").animate({ marginLeft: '-1000' });
```

#### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Starx/jUsAL/)

Comment: Sorry I didn't include the html & css.  The div is floated left so there is no "left" value and no position defined. That's why I'm using offset.left.

Comment: @fuey, On that case, you can animate `marginLeft`

Answer (score 4):

Does the styling of your element give it the ability move to the left? The following works for me just fine.

`$("#myDiv").animate({left: '-=1000'});`​

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/loktar/Zswg6/)**

Like the comment above, show us what you are using :).

Answer (score 1):

Use the animate function of jQuery to do so.

```
$('button').mouseover(function () {
    $('#mydiv').animate({left: '100px'}, 'slow'); 
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/HPpEY/

Answer (score 0):

Yeah correct javascript solutions have already been provided in the answers. You could also consider using css3 transitions. Check out a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gopi1410/CAu7c/) I wrote just now.